# Extracting text values from atom feed with Ruby RSS

Tags: ruby, rss, atom-feed

I'm trying to use the standard lib ruby `RSS::Parser` to parse an Atom feed, which sort of works.

When I access the extracted fields, such as `.title` it returns `<title>The title</title>` rather than just `The title`. If you parse e.g. a RSS feed the `.channel.title` will return `The title`.

Is there any way to use the standard `RSS::Parser` for atom feeds? or is it a bug?

I know there are alternatives like Feedzirra, but I would rather use the standard lib.

A quick test to see the problem in ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0:

```
require "rss"
feed = RSS::Parser.parse(open("http://casadelkrogh.dk/atom.xml").read)
feed.title.to_s #=> "<title>CasaDelKrogh</title>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the content of the `title` your code should be as below :

```
require "rss"
feed = RSS::Parser.parse(open("http://casadelkrogh.dk/atom.xml").read)
feed.title.to_s
# => "<title>CasaDelKrogh</title>"
feed.title.content
# => "CasaDelKrogh"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug.

`to_s` method is almost inspection of `RSS::Atom::Feed::Title`.

You can use `feed.title.content` if you want get title without tag.